# Alternative to NOT IN in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have my table in this structure. I am trying to find all the unique ID's whose word's do not appear in the list. How can I achieve this in MS SQL Server.

```
id word
1  hello
2  friends
2  world
3  cat
3  dog
2  country
1  phone
4  eyes
```

I have a list of words

```
**List**

phone 
eyes
hair
body
```

Expected Output

Except the words from the list, I need all the unique ID's. In this case it is,

```
2
3
```

I & 4 is not in the output as their words appears in the List

I tried the below code

```
Select count(distinct ID)
from Table1
where word not in ('phone','eyes','hair','body')
```

I tried Not Exists also which did not work

Comment: `NOT EXISTS`? `LEFT JOIN` and then `WHERE {LEFT JOIN TABLE}.{COLUMN} IS NULL`? What have you tried so far and why didn't it work? Why not `NOT IN` (apart fr4om it has problems with `NULL` values)?

Comment: why do you have duplicate ids?

Comment: @DanielA.White, This is how my data is.

Comment: Presumably it is a many to many table? Entity with `id=1` is related to words hello and phone?

Comment: I never understood why to use the name `id` for a non-unique column....

Comment: @ZoharPeled I will change the naming

Comment: @terry - don't change it now. It will mean all the answers you have got need adjusting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as well: this is a dynamic table structure:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (id int, word varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'hello'),
(2, 'friends'),
(2, 'world'),
(3, 'cat'),
(3, 'dog'),
(2, 'country'),
(1, 'phone'),
(4, 'eyes')

DECLARE @tblNotUsed AS TABLE ( id int, word varchar(20))
DECLARE @tblNotUsedIds AS TABLE (id int)

INSERT INTO @tblNotUsed VALUES
(1, 'phone'),
(2, 'eyes'),
(3, 'hair'),
(4, 'body')

INSERT INTO @tblNotUsedIds (id) 
SELECT [@T].id FROM @T INNER JOIN @tblNotUsed ON [@tblNotUsed].word = [@T].word

SELECT DISTINCT id FROM @T 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM @tblNotUsedIds)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT id
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN word IN('phone', 'eyes', 'hair', 'body') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: Better than my answer :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Perhaps, but you have "save us this step"

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Shorter, whether better in practice will likely depend on the OP's data and available indexes

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I found that most of the time, people that are getting answers like this actually do save us this step in future questions (especially if they end up accepting this answer), so this is my little contribution to the quality of questions, I guess...

Comment: @MartinSmith well, at least from the maintenance perspective it's better - but yes, performance wise it depends on the factors you've listed.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it is to use `not exists`, where the inner query is linked to the outer query by id and is filtered by the search words.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (
    id int, 
    word varchar(20)
)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'hello'),
(2, 'friends'),
(2, 'world'),
(3, 'cat'),
(3, 'dog'),
(2, 'country'),
(1, 'phone'),
(4, 'eyes')
```

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM @T t0
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM @T t1
    WHERE word IN('phone', 'eyes', 'hair', 'body')
    AND t0.Id = t1.Id
)
```

Result:

```
id
2
3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t.id FROM dbo.table AS t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.table AS t2
    INNER JOIN 
      (VALUES('phone'),('eyes'),('hair'),('body')) AS lw(word)
    ON t2.word = lw.word
    AND t2.id = t.id)
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about SQL is there are sometimes many ways to do things. Here is one way is to place your list of known values into a #temp table and then run something like this.

```
Select * from dbo.maintable

EXCEPT

Select * from #tempExcludeValues
```

The results will give you all records that aren't in your predefined list. A second way is to do the join like Larnu has mentioned in the comment above.  NOT IN is typically not the fastest way to do things on larger datasets.  JOINs are by far the most efficient method of filtering data.  Many times better than using a IN or NOT IN clause.